# how to capture stdout from embedded jython on java program

Tags: java, python, stdout, jython

i want to use jython on a java program,so i want to capture the stdout in jython script

then i can get the output on my java context,is there some way to archive this ?

Answer (score 0):

In jython (and cpython) you can set the stdout to a file, or file like object. Knowing this you can set the stdout to StringIO like so

```
from StringIO import StringIO
output = StringIO()
sys.stdout = output
#do stuff
output.seek(0)
output.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jython [`PythonInterpreter`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) class has [`setIn`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29), [`setOut`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#setOut%28java.io.OutputStream%29), and [`setErr`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#setErr%28java.io.OutputStream%29) methods to set the streams associated with `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` in the Python program.